# Appium: Home page is always set to default on android default browser

Tags: android, appium

When I open default browser using Appium, instead of given url, it opens default home page. Never mind if I set the home page to blank page, or something else. It works fine when opening browser manually, but when appium opens it, it is again set to default page.

I tested 2 devices with Android 4.1 and I always get the same issue on both.

This issue does not happen with Chrome browser.

Has anyone had this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with the stock Android browser using Appium, i suggest you run your tests on an emulator instead of the real real device.

Appium is compatible with Chrome on real Android devices but you can run the tests on the Stock Android browser if you use an Emulated device.

I have tried it out and it works.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for answer. 
I need to run stock browser only on real Android device.